# ClassCastException when converting from Object type to Integer type in Java

Tags: java, classcastexception

At first, excuse me if this question seems stupid. Actually, I am new to Java programing. 
I have the following code:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Object[] ob = new Object[2];
        ob[0] = new Integer("1");
        ob[1] = new Integer("2");

        Integer[] o = (Integer)ob;
        System.out.println(o.length());
    }

}
```

when compiling this code a `classCastException` exception is thrown. Why?. I know that `Object` type can not be cast to `Integer` type. But, in fact, each element of the array `ob` is an instance of `Integer` class which means the casting is logically true. Am I mistaken?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not freatebitnthe way you wsnt it in the first place? `Integer[] ob = new Integer[2];`?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not ok.

Consider if this would be valid:

```
Object[] ob = new Object[2];
ob[0] = new Integer("1");
ob[1] = new Integer("2");

Integer[] o = (Integer)ob;
ob[0] = "Hello :)";
```

What do you expect `o[0]` to return?
An `Integer`?
Or the String `"Hello"`?

This would work if you created the array with `new Integer[2]` - then you would get a `ClassCastException` when you try to put the String into it.